# Conditional probability question games

Tags: probability

I am having a problem that I am unable to solve. Can you help me with that?

I have a kindergarten and 40% of the kids up to 4 years old play video games. However, for older kids, only 15% of age older than 4 play video games. Kids under 4 account for 10% of the total kids.

a. If I select randomly 15 kids that play video games, what is the chance that at least 11 of them are 4 years old and under?

b. If I select 15 kids randomly, what is the chance that 5 are under age 4 that play video games, 2 do not play video games but smaller than 4, 6 are older than 4 and play video games and the rest do not play games?

c. Compute the expected number of kids that play video games for 15 kids.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  I should say, as stated the first two parts can't really be answered.  It depends on how many kids there are.  If there are lots and lots of kids then we can assume that the age of the first randomly selected child is independent of the age of the second, but this is not true if there are only a few kids.  the third part can be answered regardless of this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following table that represent your bivariate data

[image]

Using this table you can construct the rv required to answer to any question...

Example:

a): Selecting 15 kids at random from those who play Video Games, it results by the table that

$$\frac{4}{17.5}\approx 22.86\%$$ are under 4 Years Old... thus you can use the Binomial to answer

et cetera et cetera